# Basic java Program not returning result

Tags: java

I've been doing these basic java projects and I'm stuck on this one:
https://programmingbydoing.com/a/gender-game.html
The point of the code is to put Mr, Mrs, Ms in front of the users name.
No matter how I twist the code around I cant get it to give me a result for age>20 and gender M.

```
String gender,firstname,lastname, married;
String prefix ;
int age;

System.out.println("What is your gender (m or f): ");
gender=kb.next();
System.out.println("First name: ");
firstname=kb.next();
System.out.println("Last name: ");
lastname=kb.next();
System.out.println("Age: ");
age=kb.nextInt();

if(age<20)
    System.out.println("Then I shall call you " +firstname+" "+lastname);

if(age>=20 && gender.equals("f"))
    System.out.println("Are you married, "+firstname+"(y or n)?");
    married=kb.next();
          {if (married.equals("y"))
           prefix="Mrs. ";
           else
           prefix="Ms. ";}
          if (gender.equals("m"))
prefix="Mr. ";

System.out.println("Then I shall call you "+prefix+" "+lastname+".");  

kb.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Could you please describe in more detail exactly what problems you are having?

Comment: Watch your `if`s. Indentation is not significant in Java except for readability. If you want to have more than one statement inside the `if`, you need to put **all** of them in curly braces right after the `()`.

Comment: here is the [solution](http://ideone.com/Ylle1h) that you want

Comment: Learn to use braces.

Answer (score 0):

Your curly braces are in the wrong places in your second if. It should look like:

```
else if(age>=20)
{
    if(gender.equals("f"))
    {
        System.out.println("Are you married, "+firstname+"(y or n)?");
        married=kb.next();
        if (married.equals("y"))
           prefix="Mrs. ";
        else
           prefix="Ms. ";
    }
    else if (gender.equals("m"))
    {
        prefix="Mr. ";
    }
    System.out.println("Then I shall call you "+prefix+" "+lastname+"."); 
}
```

When you have to execute more than one line of code within an if statement, you have to place the code within curly braces. Otherwise, you'll just run the first line.

Comment: You have to check the age for the prefix of a male, too.

Comment: Now check it. I made some changes factoring in the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like this. Check the age, then check the gender

```
if(age>=20) {// I would recommend just making this an else, since you already did < 20, so testing age here a second time is a waste

    if (gender.equals("f")){

        System.out.println("Are you married, "+firstname+"(y or n)?");
        married=kb.next();

        if (married.equals("y"))
            prefix="Mrs. ";

        else
            prefix="Ms. ";
    }
    else{
        prefix="Mr. ";
    }

    System.out.println("Then I shall call you "+prefix+" "+lastname+".");  
}

kb.close();
```